# Nginx reverse-proxy based on requested URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'd like to configure my nginx as reverse-proxy which will allow me such things:

requests like:

test.xxx.dev.example.com -> xxx.domain.dev.example.com

test.yyy.dev.example.com -> yyy.domain.dev.example.com

My current config:

```
server_name ~^test/.(?<app>\w+)\.dev\.example\.com
location / {
  proxy_pass http://$app.domain.dev.example.com/;
}
```

I'm getting 502 error. Logs say: no resolver defined to resolve .domain.dev.example.com :( Any help?

Edit1: When added resolver 127.0.0.11 (this is docker-compose based env), error "no resolver defined to resolve..." disappears, but new one appear:

.domain.dev.example.com could not be resolved, host not found. It seems like for some reasons, variable $app is not passed to proxy_pass directive. Any idea ?

Comment: Nginx documentation describes `resolver` directive [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).

Comment: Already fixed, but new error appears. See my edited post. thx

Comment: You may need to `set` a variable, and use that variable in the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this link](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215830,215832#msg-215832) or [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p)

Comment: You have mistype in `server_name`. I assume there should be backward slash in there: `test\.(?<app>\w+)\....`, but I guess you've already fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems like the problem was with resolver and wrong regex. Below config works as expected for me:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^test\.(?<app>.+)\.dev\.example\.com$;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://$app.domain.dev.example.com$url;
  }
}
```

@Richard in my regex, I'm declaring variable and value :) this is done by "?<'app>" where app is variable name.

Thanks for all the hints and help!